# Question regarding the usage of 'As in'

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

'The multi-storey pagoda came to Japan from China in the sixth century. *As in* China, they were first introduced with Buddhism and were attached to important temples.'

I initially thought this meant *Pagoda was introduced in China with Buddhism*

However, the answer to a question regarding whether China or Japan, or Both, initially had a religious purpose for the pagodas, was BOTH. (No latter parts of the passage state anything about religious purpose, only this sentence)

Does that mean *As in* here is *Just like in*?

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean As in here is Just like in?

Yes

> No latter parts of the passage state anything about religious purpose, only this sentence

This is implied by "*attached to important temples*"

> I initially thought this meant Pagoda was introduced in China with Buddhism

This is what the sentence is also saying but the focus is on the Japanese introduction of pagodas being the same *as in* China.